# Nginx proxy with SSL Authentication

Tags: nginx, ssl

My proxy needs to be mutually authenticated, and the forwarded-to server (in another cluster) needs to be mutually authenticated. Therefore, the proxy needs to forward the request to that server using its own SSL identity, and forward the original certificate key and public key from the request to the server via headers.

Based on the documentation, it doesn't *seem* possible with the standard proxy module. Maybe with another module?

Comment: I didn't actually understand what you want and why it would be impossible, but I remember messing around with nginx proxy and ssl a while ago, with the help of this tutorial. Not sure if it helps because it only refers to using one SSL certificate to auth basically into the proxy. (are you somehow trying to proxy a connection to a ssl proxt to another ssl proxy using other certs?) http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-unix-setup-nginx-ssl-proxy/

Comment: Nah.. They're solution is stripping the SSL from the request, going into the next server: proxy_pass  http://nixcraft;

Comment: I rephrase the original question.